# How to make Powerapps work with Param function in Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to create a powerapps web part that will open a specific screen from a canvas app using parameters. I have added the web part and added the power apps web link to it. When I enter *&parametername=parameter* nothing shows up. I can enter the web link and parameters directly into a browser window (tried in Chrome and Edge) and the app will display properly. I can also created a button in a web part and added the link to it and it will also display the app when the button is clicked. The app is working properly with no errors, it will just not show up in the web part when the parameters are added to the link (If no parameters are added to the link, everything will display fine).

I am trying to create a powerapps web part that will open a specific screen from a canvas app using parameters. I have added the web part and added the power apps web link to it. When I enter *&parametername=parameter* nothing shows up. I can enter the web link and parameters directly into a browser window (tried in Chrome and Edge) and the app will display properly. I can also created a button in a web part and added the link to it and it will also display the app when the button is clicked. The app is working properly with no errors, it will just not show up in the web part when the parameters are added to the link (If no parameters are added to the link, everything will display fine).

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this myself; just figured it out.

You need to put the *full* URL *with parameters* in to the "App web link or ID" property for the PowerApp web part. Be careful because the first parameter needs to be prepended with `?` **not** `&`. The ampersand is used for additional, following parameters after the first parameter.

[image: Custom PowerApp Canvas Screen in PowerApp web part]

Note that I have omitted my TLD from this screenshot, however you will want to substitute your own here.

The example URL syntax [given by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/how-to/deep-linking#create-the-deep-link-url) is `https://apps.powerapps.com/play/{App ID}?{Query}`. For me that URL looks something like this:

`https://apps.powerapps.com/play/f813580f-3182-90b0-b3a9-781cfb288808?linkId=checkIn`

I have one URL for `checkIn` and another for `checkOut` that I can use to display different forms.

My primary mistake was that I was *only* pasting my `appID` into the "App web link or ID" field rather than the entire URL. Remember, you can edit your Canvas Form, click on "Share" and get the Web Link from this page. This contains the full URL, minus your custom parameters. Play around with the full URL plus parameters until you get something that the web part will accept.